# iTextSharp: Getting error 'Not enough memory available to complete this command' while signing pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have been working on PDF Signing project and I am using iTextsharp to sign the PDF. I have 10000 PDFs that I want to digitally sign but unfortunately I am getting error 'Not enough memory available to complete this command.' at below line. I googled for the same but it would not helped for C#.

```
MakeSignature.SignDetached(SignatureAppearance, ExternalSignature, Certificates, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

I am not able to find exact reason for this error as I have enough RAM (4GB) to process this application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Please refer the below code.

```
using (FileStream SignedPDF = new FileStream(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", this.DestinationFolder, Path.GetFileName(this.Form16FileName)), FileMode.Create))
{
    using (PdfStamper PDFStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(PdfReader, SignedPDF, '\0', this.DestinationFolder))
    {
        PdfSignatureAppearance SignatureAppearance = PDFStamper.SignatureAppearance;

        if (PasswordProtectGeneratedPDF)
        {
            PDFStamper.SetEncryption(true, this.FilePassword, this.FilePassword, 0);
        }

        //TODO: Here set signatureAppearance at your will
        //signatureAppearance.Location = "Mumbai";
        try
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Image Watermark = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("tick.jpg");
            SignatureAppearance.Image = Watermark;
            SignatureAppearance.Image.ScaleToFit(70, 70);
            //appearance.Image.Alignment=100;
            SignatureAppearance.Image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
            SignatureAppearance.GetAppearance().AddImage(Watermark);
        }
        catch 
        { 
        }
        SignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(500, 100, 450, 50), PageNumber, null);
        SignatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(SignatureAppearance, ExternalSignature, Certificates, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Same code is working properly when I run it under Visual Studio Profiler.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/